# Find best parameter values: minimise some while maximizing others (in R)?

Tags: r, optimization, valuation

I have several variables (A, B, C) which are independent statistical measures. Each of these vary for different values of my function's parameter X.

The plots of A,B,C look something like this:
[image: A,B,C for different X]

I would like to write an "optimization function" to find at which value of X the following criterion are best satisfied:

- A is maximised
- B is minimized
- C is maximized

Since these requirements sometimes oppose each other, this naturally requires a compromise.

What is the best way to approach this type of problem (in R)?

Comment: The signs for A and B in your function seem to be reversed from what you want, for maximizing A and C while minimizing B.

Comment: Thank you. I moved the question about the function programming to stackoverflow, since that is a whole other question not suitable for cross-validated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a case of [multi-objective optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-objective_optimization), which is a field of study all on its own. Look through the Wikipedia article for inspiration.

Whatever you do, you will need to decide on a relative weighting of your components. Is a small increase in A worth a larger increase in B?

The simplest way ("linear scalarization") would certainly be to define weights $w_A, w_B, w_C>0$, then maximize

$$w_AA(x)-w_BB(x)+w_CC(x)\to\max$$

Note how the minus sign in front of the $w_BB(x)$ term encodes that we want to minimize $B(x)$ (that is, maximize $-B(x)$). This optimization with respect to $x$ can easily be fed into `optim()` or other appropriate R optimization routines.

Comment: Thanks Stephan for your answer - this is very helpful! I will have a look at the optim library in R. Each variable is a statistic which explains a different property of my data, so I would be inclined to think they have the same importance. I am worried that by weighting the variables, I may be introducing a bias into my results?

Comment: You may be interested in the [CRAN task view on optimization](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html). To be honest, you don't have a choice *not* to weight. Giving each component an equal weight is simply one very particular weighting scheme. You will need to decide based on your particular use case, possibly also using something more sophisticated than simple linear weighting. Also look at the possible ranges of your components. Good luck!